# Drop down menu for field value, with a new value option in user/register

Tags: web2py

I have a yearbook application where users have to enter their details on registration. One such field is 'university'. I want the university to be chosen from a drop-down menu containing all universities in the database (like when using the validator IS_IN_DB()), with the option to enter the university name if the university does not exist in the database.This should appear in the user/register form. How do I implement this in web2py?

Please note: I am very new to web2py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing built in to web2py to handle this case, but you might get some inspiration from these recipes:

- http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1616/widget-select-or-add-option-ng
- http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1446/widget-select-or-add-option

Comment: Thanks, I'll go through them. But when you say there is no way to handle this case in web2py, do you mean there's no way to modify user/register's form, or no way to implement the type of form I need?

Comment: You can certainly modify the registration form and do exactly what you want, there just isn't a built in solution - it will require some coding.